# UPDATE CADENA SQL SERVER

Tags: mysql, sql-server, base-de-datos, mysqli, datatables

Quisiera saber como poder actualizar los dos primeros digitos de una cadena en un campo

necesito actualizar CH_H_AJUS de 0727 a 0627, unicamente actualizar el 7 por un 6, y son mas de 2k registros.

[image: IMAGEN]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que tienes que hacer es extraer los caracteres de la cadena que no deseas perder, luego añades los nuevos caracteres, en la siguiente consulta puedes ver como se modifica el dato en la columna new...:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que falta es hacer el update:

```
UPDATE tablename SET CH_H_AJUS = SUBSTRING(CH_H_AJUS, 1, 1) + '6' + SUBSTRING(CH_H_AJUS, 3, LEN(CH_H_AJUS)) WHERE CH_H_AJUS LIKE '07%' OR CH_H_AJUS LIKE '17%' OR CH_H_AJUS LIKE '27%' OR CH_H_AJUS LIKE '37%' OR CH_H_AJUS LIKE '47%' OR CH_H_AJUS LIKE '57%' OR CH_H_AJUS LIKE '67%' OR CH_H_AJUS LIKE '77%' OR CH_H_AJUS LIKE '87%' OR CH_H_AJUS LIKE '97%';
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> EDIT:

En el caso del ID 5, antes de hacer el UPDATE actualicé el registro por eso aparece "1", eso para que veas que no importa el primer caracter, siempre va modificar el segundo caracter.

Answer (score 1):

Si todos los datos son como los que muestras en la imagen, es decir, que comienzan por `07` y tienen 4 caracteres de longitud, es tan sencillo como:

```
UPDATE nombre_tabla SET CH_H_AJUS = '06' + SUBSTRING(CH_H_AJUS, 3, 2)
```

Si por el contrario no todos comienzan por `07` o no todos tienen 4 caracteres de longitud, puedes actualizar la pregunta con nuevos datos y actualizo mi respuesta.